# Can we install a slide in gas range with convection oven outdoors?

Tags: kitchens, outdoor, oven, range

I am planning to build a simple summer/outdoor kitchen in the covered patio. Even though the patio is covered it gets occasional rain and a lot of sun. I don't need a grill but need a good gas cooktop along with a conventional oven for baking.

A sample product that I am looking is similar to [KitchenAid freestanding oven with gas range](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/kitchenaid-6-0-cu-ft-self-cleaning-free-standing-double-oven-gas-convection-range-stainless-steel/5487029.p?skuId=5487029&ref=212&loc=1&ref=212&loc=1&ds_rl=1260669&ds_rl=1273104&ds_rl=1273104&gclid=CjwKCAjwxuuCBhATEiwAIIIz0ZoRmszXPnlEvw9RYM2Ej2y5XrmNjcXKhtKUcY7vOSnALp_Wi4SySBoCMTUQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: _Can_ you? Sure! Is the one you linked to (as a "sample") a good oven? Dunno, and that's a product recommendation question that's off topic. Is it rated for outdoor use? Dunno, what do the product specs say? I haven't been in a Worst Buy in ages, but last I was, they didn't specialize in outdoor cooking. Maybe things have changed. I'd recommend doing some internet searching for "outdoor convection oven" to find suitable units. That's about the most "product recommendation" an answer you'll manage to get here.

Comment: What's the climate where you live?  What is the hottest day and the coldest night each year?  I'd be worried about the electronics being ruined by abnormal amounts of moisture, the plastics and rubber being ruined by being baked in the sun constantly, about rain or condensation freezing at night and breaking or ruining parts, about insects and racoons getting into the oven, about pine needles, pollen, tree sap. etc covering and ruining the surfaces, and so on.  I'd buy something designed for outdoors that has a cover and no electronics.

Comment: The real question would be how close to the edge of the roof will the oven be? I have wired exterior stove tops in the past I always recommend they be installed in the center area (opposite of most plans that have them in the perimeter)  the 1 person that changed plans has not called me back to repair or replace. With 1 customer complaining as I wired in the 3rd stove top (electric) I asked him if he could find an electric stove top that could be washed off with a hose. He thought that was silly until I showed him the electrical box that was full of water. It’s covered now when not in use

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer with a practical suggestion, rather than precisely answering the "Can we" question with "you can!".

A complex appliance designed for indoors, full of electronic controls and sensors, and lots of hidden inaccessible crevices where moisture and insects can collect, is unlikely to last long outside, or to work at all in some extreme outdoor temperatures.

Look at specialty outdoor cooking web sites and vendors.

Buy a gas cooktop designed for outdoor use.  They exist, and they are designed in a way that can withstand most of the things that the outdoors can throw at them (sun, snow, etc ... maybe not bears).  Outdoor ovens are harder to find.  There are lots of pizza ovens designed for outdoors. They can be used for more than just pizza. And if there are some things that require a conventional oven, you can cook those inside.  Why do you need to, for example, bake a cake outdoors?  That's probably not how you'll get most of the enjoyment from your outdoor setup so move that bit back inside.